# Java JFrame not refreshed on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, swing

I have a Java Application that consists of 2 JFrames. One is used only for a preview and houses a custom JComponent. The other Frame consists of several Input Fields wich control the output of the preview.

I have action listeners for the various input fields that force a redraw of the custom JComponent using

```
previewRenderer.update(previewRenderer.getGraphics());
```

where the previewRenderer is the custom JComponent on the other JFrame.

This works well on Linux & Windows, however on Mac OSX the 2nd JFrame did not update at all.

I don't have an OSX Machine at hand for testing, but how can I force a redraw of the other Frame, respectively the custom JComponent?

Thanks in advace.

Comment: It could be a thread issue.  Are you ensuring that all code that touches the view is run in the event dispatch thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to

```
previewRenderer.repaint()
```

or maybe even

```
previewRenderer.repaint()
previewRenderer.revalidate()
```

depending on what changes you are doing in the components of the preview frame.

Comment: the previewRenderer Compponent has a special paint Method that needs to be called.

Comment: Not sure how you implemented this but these methods are calling the appropriate methods to force painting/repainting the whole component so I think it should work ok. But maybe you already tried?

Comment: Yes it works of Linux but I can't test on Mac OS X yet. I need this to be working on Mac.

Comment: Ok, I see. We develop for Mac OS X and this is how we do it so if you are not doing something very different in your component I think you should be ok :)